# items in array to drag and change their positions while dropping in React

Tags: reactjs

Am just looking for a workaround for my doubt in React
As i have an array and it have elements like

```
[{'name':A},{'name':B},{'name':C},{'name':D}]
```

and these items will be aligning like vertically one after another, say A first followed by B, then C and D
My task it to rearrange the divs and change their positions.
Like if i change A to C , then B should come first and then A.
like wise its like changing the order with drag and drop and save the order , once the user done with latest reorder

I searched many and a newbie and still learning , so if you guys can help me with a link or anything will be helpful

React version is 17.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this demo

File: App.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Reorder, {
  reorder,
  reorderImmutable,
  reorderFromTo,
  reorderFromToImmutable
} from "react-reorder";
import move from "lodash-move";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([
    "qeqwe",
    "jjshh",
    "piaif",
    "asjdhgj"
  ]);

  const onReorder = (e, from, to) => {
    setList(move(list, from, to));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React Reorder</h1>
      <hr />
      <div
        style={{
          background: "#ddd",
          padding: 20
        }}
      >
        <Reorder
          reorderId="my-list" // Unique ID that is used internally to track this list (required)
          reorderGroup="reorder-group" // A group ID that allows items to be dragged between lists of the same group (optional)
          // getRef={this.storeRef.bind(this)} // Function that is passed a reference to the root node when mounted (optional)
          component="div" // Tag name or Component to be used for the wrapping element (optional), defaults to 'div'
          placeholderClassName="placeholder" // Class name to be applied to placeholder elements (optional), defaults to 'placeholder'
          draggedClassName="dragged" // Class name to be applied to dragged elements (optional), defaults to 'dragged'
          lock="horizontal" // Lock the dragging direction (optional): vertical, horizontal (do not use with groups)
          holdTime={500} // Default hold time before dragging begins (mouse & touch) (optional), defaults to 0
          touchHoldTime={500} // Hold time before dragging begins on touch devices (optional), defaults to holdTime
          mouseHoldTime={200} // Hold time before dragging begins with mouse (optional), defaults to holdTime
          onReorder={onReorder} // Callback when an item is dropped (you will need this to update your state)
          autoScroll={true} // Enable auto-scrolling when the pointer is close to the edge of the Reorder component (optional), defaults to true
          disabled={false} // Disable reordering (optional), defaults to false
          disableContextMenus={true} // Disable context menus when holding on touch devices (optional), defaults to true
          placeholder={
            <div className="custom-placeholder" /> // Custom placeholder element (optional), defaults to clone of dragged element
          }
        >
          {list.map(item => (
            <div
              style={{
                height: 50,
                background: "grey",
                margin: "10px 0px",
                cursor: "pointer"
              }}
              key={item}
            >
              {item}
            </div>
          ))
    
          }
        </Reorder>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

File: style.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.dragged {
  background: white;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou @Mr.Gandhi , but am getting some error on copying code and pasting . something i might be missing , can you help with a working fiddle or

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/41i2i

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kdwurp?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css

Comment: i just tried this , but am not getting the right way. am trying in jsx , not sure about typescript. Can you please help me on above code to work it

Comment: can you help on above stackblitz code as well

Comment: Try with react version 16

Comment: no luck , i was using react "react": "^17.0.2", not working , even i tried with version 16, thats also not working

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: Gandhi for react latest version 17.0.2, its NOT working